# Is there a way to do a string.Split on whitespace

Tags: c#, string

I have a string `"mystring     theEnd"`  but I want to do a string.Split on white space, not just on a space because I want to get a `string[]` that contains "mystring" and "theEnd"  between "mystring" and "theEnd" there is an unknown amount of spaces, this is why I need to split on whitespace.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is it always going to be spaces or can it be any form of whitespace?

Comment: @HenkHolterman In the question he just specified that it would be multiple spaces. I wanted to know if it would also be things like tabs. As it turns out from the comments below, he's looking for tabs also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
string[] bits = text.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptEntries);
```

(Or `text.Split` specifying the exact whitespace characters you want to split on, or using `null` as Henk suggested.)

Or you could use a regex to handle *all* whitespace characters:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\s+");
string[] bits = regex.Split(text);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest is to do:

```
a.Split(new [] {' ', '\t'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Thanks Jon :)

Comment: This does not include tabs, which I forgot to mention that I need to account for

Comment: That won't compile at the moment - you need to provide a `char[]`, and because it's not the last parameter in that overload, it isn't a `params` parameter.

Comment: Then you need to go with the regex approach above and search for spaces and tabs.